# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'member_count'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is my code.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', description='A random bot')
.
.
.
guild = bot.get_guild(760036721978507266)
member_count = guild.member_count
print(member_count)
```

I am trying to get the number of members (excluding bots) but returning

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/X/Desktop/Coding/bot/new.py", line 626, in everymin
    member_count = guild.member_count
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'member_count'
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `bot.get_guild()` is returning None as there is no such guild with the given id

Comment: well I guess the id is correct. I copied it from command `await ctx.send(f"{ctx.guild.id}")`